# Return 0 in sql if no row is found

Tags: sql

```
SELECT count(STATUS) AS STATUS, USER_ID
from Table1
WHERE USER_ID = '65'
group by STATUS, USER_ID
order by STATUS
```

Return 0 in sql if no row is found

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Which sql you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, your qualifier is that User_Id must exist.  So simply check for that.

```
if Exists(Select * from Table1 where User_Id=65)
SELECT count(STATUS) AS STATUS, USER_ID from Table1 WHERE USER_ID = '65' group by STATUS, USER_ID order by STATUS
else Select 0 as Status, 65 as User_Id
```

Obviously use a variable in your final code instead of "65" and I am assuming that you actually want to search for multiple rows eg (where user_id in (xx,xx,xx,xx,) otherwise as others have pointed out, the order by is redundant.

Another approach is to do a cross apply on the table from the list of users you want to test which will produce a list of users and then the count (again assuming that you want to actually return multiple rows).

Comment: It's just for sampling, but it has a dedicated parameter

Comment: I changed the value to the parameter, and it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Alphatrix: this answer is non-standard SQL (there is no `IF` in standard SQL). Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you remove the `group by`, the query will always return 1 row.  This should return one row with `count(STATUS)` equal to `0` if the user is not found:

```
SELECT  '65'
,       count(STATUS) AS STATUS
FROM    Table1
WHERE   USER_ID = '65'
```

Alternatively, you can use a `union` to present a row with `0` when the user is not present:

```
SELECT  USER_ID
,       count(STATUS) AS STATUS
FROM    Table1
WHERE   USER_ID = '65'
GROUP BY
        USER_ID
UNION ALL
SELECT  '65'
,       0
WHERE   NOT EXISTS 
        (
        SELECT  *
        FROM    Table1 
        WHERE   USER_ID = '65'
        )
```

EDIT (from gordon):

If you are averse to having the user id occur twice, then simply do:

```
select u.user_id, count(t1.status)
from (select 65 as user_id) u left join
     table1 t1 
     on t1.user_id = u.user_id
group by u.user_id;
```

Comment: I also want to show the column USER_ID, and 65 is just for sampling it has a dedicated parameter

Comment: What's the problem with the dedicated parameter? Replace each occurrence of 65 with the parameter?

Comment: @Alphatrix . . . The first query is the best answer to this question.

Answer (score 0):

Not so elegant, maybe..but it works:

```
Select count(*) from (

SELECT count(STATUS) AS STATUS, USER_ID from Table1 WHERE USER_ID = '65' group by STATUS, USER_ID
) as t
```

I only removed your order by, irrelevant into a count

Answer (score 0):

This is usually done with an outer join: select the user and outer join the status data.

It makes no sense by the way, to group by status and not show the column in your results. What would the results tell you if you got 65-4, 65-2, 65-8 in your results, not knowing which count belongs to which status?

```
select count(*), t1.status, u.user_id
from users u
left join table1 t1 on t1.user_id = u.user_id
where u.user_id = 65
group by t1.status, u.user_id
order by t1.status;
```

It might be even better to also have a status table and then outer join table1, so as to get all possible statuses with their number of occurrences including zeros. (For more than one user you'd then cross join the statuses with the users first; for a single user you wouldn't, but put `user_id = 65` in the `ON` clause.)